# Heatmap in Grid with normalized color intensity based on highest value among all heatmaps

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to plot a number of heatmaps in a grid and would like to have the heat colors based on 0 to max value of all heat maps, so that the heat legend is comparable among the several heatmaps and have the same range of heats in color legends. As it has to be done for any data matrices provided, here is Rscript that I have till now to create heatmap while also restricting max value of individual heatmaps to 99 percentile, which is another required I need to keep. So, I would finally be looking at the max value after capping each heatmaps to 99 percentile. Please suggest how can I implement similar heat scaling.

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
options(echo=F) # if you want see commands in output file
setwd("./")
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
numArgs<-length(args)
print(numArgs-2)
if(args[1] == "-h"){
writeLines("\nTo run : Rscript readDensity_heatmap.R <base name of tag dir folder> <sample 1> <sample 2>")
writeLines("e.g Rscript readDensity_heatmap.R Peaks <dataMatrix1 dataMatrix2 .......\n")
stop("", call.=F)
writeLines("\n")
}else if(numArgs < 3){
stop("Please supply 3 arguments")
}
library(pheatmap)
library(gplots)
library(reshape2)
library(fields)
z=3
for (i in 1:as.integer(args[2])){
eqn<-paste("cond", i, '<-colsplit("', args[z], '", "_",', 'c("a", "b" ))', sep="" )
eval(parse(text=eqn))
z=z+1
}
var_names <- paste("file", 1:(numArgs-1), sep="")
df_names <- paste("df", 1:(numArgs-1), sep="")
d=1
j=3
prefix<-args[1]
pdf(paste0(prefix, "_readDensityHeatmap_TFs.pdf"), height=20, width=10)
par(mfrow=c(10,3))
par(mar=c(3,3,3,3))
for (i in 1:(numArgs-2)){
var_names[d]=paste("HeatMatrix/", prefix, "_", args[j], "_HeatMatrix.txt", sep="")
if (!file.exists(var_names[d]) ){
writeLines(paste('"', var_names[d], '"', "not present\n", sep=" "))
stop(" ")
}
lhs<-df_names[d]
rhs<-paste('read.delim("', var_names[d], '"' , ",header=T, sep='\t')", sep="")
dfEqn=paste(lhs, "<-", rhs, sep="")
eval(parse(text=dfEqn))
eqn<-paste0("x<-df", d)
eval(parse(text=eqn))
x<-x[,-1]
x<-x[order(rowMeans(x)),]
quantile.range <- quantile(as.matrix(x), probs = seq(0, 1, 0.01))
palette.breaks <- seq(quantile.range["0%"], quantile.range["99%"], .001)
mycol <- colorpanel(n=length(palette.breaks)-1,low="white",mid="blue",high="red")
eqn<-paste0("cond<-cond", d, "$a" ) #
eval(parse(text=eqn))
eqn<-paste0("condp2<-cond", d, "$b" ) #
eval(parse(text=eqn))
image(as.matrix(t(x)), col=mycol,breaks=palette.breaks, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", axes=F, main=paste(cond, condp2, sep=" ") )
mtext(text=c(-2000, 0, 2000), side=1, line=0.3, at=c(0, 0.5, 1), las=1, cex=0.8)
image.plot(as.matrix(t(x)), col=mycol,breaks=palette.breaks,legend.only=T )
d=d+1
j=j+1
}
########################
dev.off()
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time-start.time
time.taken
```

Edit: Samples file. Just 50 columns (out of 400) around the center of peak and only 10 rows from several thousand. Several such files are read based on first, second and third onwards arguments provided to the script. First argument provides the base name of the file, 2nd tells how many files to read from the names that follow second arguments (these can be as many as user want to supply)

```
-270    -260    -250    -240    -230    -220    -210    -200    -190    -180    -170    -160    -150    -140    -130    -120    -110    -100    -90 -80 -70 -60 -50 -40 -30 -20 -10 0   10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190 200 210 220 230
4.47767857142857    4.47767857142857    4.47767857142857    4.21428571428571    4.47767857142857    4.21428571428571    5.26785714285714    5.26785714285714    4.74107142857143    4.74107142857143    5.53125 6.05803571428571    6.05803571428571    6.05803571428571    5.26785714285714    5.53125 6.58482142857143    6.84821428571429    6.84821428571429    7.11160714285714    7.11160714285714    6.84821428571429    7.11160714285714    7.63839285714286    7.63839285714286    8.42857142857143    9.21875 8.95535714285714    9.21875 8.95535714285714    8.16517857142857    7.90178571428571    8.69196428571429    8.16517857142857    7.63839285714286    7.11160714285714    7.375   7.375   7.11160714285714    6.32142857142857    6.05803571428572    5.79464285714286    5.53125 5.26785714285715    4.47767857142857    3.95089285714286    3.42410714285715    3.42410714285715    2.89732142857143    2.37053571428572    1.84375
5.53125 5.79464285714286    6.05803571428571    6.32142857142857    6.58482142857143    6.58482142857143    6.84821428571428    7.90178571428571    7.63839285714286    7.90178571428571    7.63839285714286    7.63839285714286    8.16517857142857    8.95535714285714    8.42857142857143    8.42857142857143    7.90178571428571    7.90178571428571    7.63839285714286    7.63839285714286    7.63839285714286    7.63839285714286    7.11160714285714    6.05803571428571    5.79464285714286    5.79464285714286    5.53125 5.26785714285714    5.26785714285714    5.00446428571429    4.47767857142857    4.21428571428571    5.00446428571429    5.00446428571429    5.00446428571429    4.47767857142857    3.95089285714286    4.47767857142857    4.74107142857143    4.47767857142857    4.74107142857143    4.74107142857143    4.21428571428571    3.6875  3.6875  3.6875  3.6875  3.6875  3.6875  3.6875  3.6875
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857   0.263392857142857
1.58035714285714    2.37053571428571    2.89732142857143    2.63392857142857    3.95089285714286    4.21428571428571    4.47767857142857    4.47767857142857    4.47767857142857    4.47767857142857    4.74107142857143    4.74107142857143    5.00446428571428    5.26785714285714    5.79464285714286    6.05803571428571    6.05803571428571    7.11160714285714    7.375   7.375   7.63839285714285    7.90178571428571    8.16517857142857    8.42857142857143    8.42857142857143    7.375   7.63839285714285    7.375   6.32142857142857    5.79464285714285    6.32142857142857    6.32142857142857    6.58482142857143    6.32142857142857    6.32142857142857    6.58482142857143    6.05803571428571    5.79464285714285    5.53125 5.26785714285714    4.74107142857143    4.47767857142857    4.21428571428571    3.6875  3.42410714285714    2.89732142857143    2.37053571428571    2.37053571428571    2.37053571428571    1.84375 2.10714285714286
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3.95089285714286    4.47767857142857    4.21428571428571    4.74107142857143    4.74107142857143    4.74107142857143    5.00446428571429    5.26785714285714    5.26785714285714    5.53125 5.53125 5.79464285714286    6.05803571428571    6.32142857142857    6.05803571428571    7.11160714285714    7.375   7.90178571428571    7.63839285714286    7.63839285714286    8.16517857142857    9.21875 10.0089285714286    9.74553571428571    9.74553571428571    9.74553571428571    9.48214285714285    9.48214285714285    9.74553571428571    9.48214285714285    9.74553571428571    9.48214285714285    9.48214285714285    9.21875 9.74553571428571    9.48214285714285    9.74553571428571    9.48214285714285    8.69196428571428    8.16517857142857    7.90178571428571    7.63839285714285    7.11160714285714    7.11160714285714    6.84821428571428    6.05803571428571    6.05803571428571    6.32142857142857    6.05803571428571    5.79464285714285    5.79464285714285
0   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.526785714285714   0.263392857142857   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: @ Sudhir, if I have understood it correctly, do you want to plot several heat maps with a common legend?

Comment: not just that the legend be same but heatmaps should have heats spanning from 0 to max of the values being plotted in all the heatmaps. This will enable me to compare these heatmaps without looking at the legend axis dynamic range...

Comment: Ok. I would first try to store all the values (from all heat maps) in a vector, get the quantiles and then plot it. If you can post a minimum working example, I could try myself. Input file is missing in above code, probably, just post minimal data.

Comment: @Amit: I have provided a sample file. Just 10 rows and 50 columns. Several such files will be read by the script based on the arguments provided, so I need to calculated max from all of them. So, to mimick that you can probably randomly change some values in this file to create diffnt input files.

Comment: @Amit : any luck on this?

Comment: Ok, I have given a thought over it. E.g., for 2 different matrices `mat1`, `mat2`, you can get a common range by `ran = c(mat1,mat2)` and then get `col_breaks = seq (0, max(ran),length=100)` and then get your `colPal = colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))(99)`. Use these `col_breaks` and `colPal` for heat maps. At least, I used similar process some time back.

Comment: @Amit : thanks for that. Meanwhile I used a similar approach, and it worked. Thanks alot.

Comment: Get. Could you post your approach and accept it.